# cakephp 3 authentication with email claims that username column doesn't exist

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I've setup Digest Authentication with email instead of username and tried to configure it properly according to the cookbook. Unfortunately some things are not totally clear. So when trying to edit a User on my cakephp3 application it returns the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: Column users.username doesn't exist LINE 1: SELECT Users.id AS "Users__id", Users.username AS "Users__us... ^
```

The Other Crud Actions work though: Create Users, List Users and View a User doesn't return an error. But Login and Delete doesn't work either and in my pgAdmin there seems to be no data row inserted though data was shown (maybe a problem with my elasticsearch plugin?)

I've configured it like this:

CreateUsers Migration:

```
public function change()
{
    $table = $this->table('users', ['id' => false, 'primary_key' => ['id']]);
    $table->addColumn('id', 'uuid');
    $table->addColumn('email', 'string', [
        'default' => null,
        'limit' => 254,
        'null' => false,
    ]);
    $table->addColumn('password', 'binary', [
        'default' => null,
        'null' => false,
    ]);
    $table->addColumn('created', 'datetime', [
        'default' => null,
        'null' => false,
    ]);
    $table->addColumn('modified', 'datetime', [
        'default' => null,
        'null' => false,
    ]);
    $table->create();
}
```

AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Digest' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email'],
                'userModel' => 'Users',
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ],
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Dazu hast du keine Rechte...',
        'storage' => 'Memory',
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
    ]);
}
```

UsersController:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // Load the Type using the 'Elastic' provider.
    $this->loadModel('Users', 'Elastic');

    $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view']);
    if (!$this->Auth->user()){
        $this->Auth->allow('add');
    }
}

public function edit($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

User Entity:

```
class User extends Entity
{
    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        if (strlen($password) > 0) {
            return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
        }
    }
}
```

UsersTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp', [
        'events' => [
            'Model.beforeSave' => [
                'created_at' => 'new',
                'modified_at' => 'always'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}

public function beforeSave(Event $event)
{
    $entity = $event->data['entity'];

    // Make a password for digest auth.
    $entity->password = DigestAuthenticate::password(
        $entity->email, //maybe change to username
        $entity->plain_password,
        env('SERVER_NAME')
    );

    $entity->created = Time::now();
    return true;
}

public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select(['id', 'username', 'password'])
        ->where(['Users.active' => 1]);

    return $query;
}
```

Template "Users Edit" View:

```
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
<ul class="side-nav">
    <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Form->postLink(
            __('Delete'),
            ['action' => 'delete', $user->id],
            ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]
        )
    ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index']) ?>     </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="users form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Edit User') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

The only thing I can see from the error message is that it might be a problem from the core in cakephp, at which I wouldn't hardcode any changes into, and the documentation doesn't clearly mention a step when using email instead of username column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UsersTable->findAuth() you try to select the field 'username'. the field does not exist, so you get a mysql-error.

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select(['id', 'username', 'password'])
        ->where(['Users.active' => 1]);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: when commenting this part out (also when configuring the auth component) it worked fine!. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function initialize() {         
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'],
                    'scope' => ['status' => 1]
                ]
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => '/',
            'logoutRedirect' => '/',
            'loginAction' => ['prefix' => false, 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']
        ]);
    }
```

in the given example username is cake auth format.In this email is table field.username is not table field. so no need username field in users table.
'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'],